# Can non-array continuous block of data be accessed by pointer with index?

Tags: c++

If i have `struct` with several `int`s, is this possible to access them like in array?
`int`s will have decreasing addresses due to stack allocation but will be continuous.
I have code similar to this

```
struct z
{
  static int a;
  static int b;
  static int c;
  static int d;
  static int e;

  static int get(int index)
  {
    int* p = &e;
    return p[index];
  }
};

int z::a = 1;
int z::b = 2;
int z::b = 3;
int z::d = 4;
int z::e = 5;

int main()
{
  int a = z::get(2);
}
```

I wonder if this will be always possible and if i even should do something like this.

Comment: `p[index]` has undefined behaviour when `index` is not 0. It may appear to work, but it's not a valid C++ program.

Comment: `ints will have decreasing addresses due to stack allocation` - variables with static storage duration are typically not allocated on the stack

Comment: `p[index]` is [equivalent to `*(p+index)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1.sentence-5). You may not perform pointer arithmetic [if you don't have an array](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.3), which is your case. Your code is therefore illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder ... if i even should do something like this.

You shouldn't. The behaviour of your program is undefined.

> If i have struct with several ints, is this possible to access them like in array?

No, it is not possible (at least not in this simple way).

If you want to access like an array, you should use an array:

```
struct z
{
  static int e[5];

  static int get(int index)
  {
    return e[index];
  }
};

int z::e = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

Comment: I am returning to this topic after some time because I didn't have time to write code, and I have new question about alignment of variables in struct: what about their addresses? If I hane struct wiith only static variables, do their addresses can change or if I assign their addresses relative to struct address and put them in lookup table, can I then access it sort of like in array through lookup table?